# MOSFET replacement / equivalent

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm looking for a replacement or an equivalent MOSFET to replace 6R190C6. Seems to be a 600 V MOSFET and only available in large quantities.

Comment: You might want to edit your title.

Comment: @Spehro I'm a bit disappointed with the edit. The previous title was much funnier.

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect and a rookie electrical guy make for quite the show!

Comment: @dim It was a small thing.

Comment: @Spehro But anyway, the question will probably be dwarfed by the close votes.

Comment: Hahaha all the puns.

Answer (score 0):

How hard did you look? Digikey has 80 IPA60R190C6 in stock and thousands of IPB60R190C6ATMA1 in stock

Comment: I guess I get nervous when I see the IPA in front of the part number. Kind of new to the electronics world.

Comment: India Pale Ale is nothing to get nervous about, nor is IsoPropyl Alcohol. But generally you need the whole part number (prefix and suffix) to be sure, and they're often not marked on the parts because there isn't enough room.

Comment: Saw the IPA and got a little thirsty, I'll have to settle for one after work.

Comment: Gotcha, I greatly appreciate the help.